# Jquery.css через цикл не работает, уже долго пытаюсь исправить, но ничего не выходит, подскажите решение?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Оснвоная проблема в том что если поменять i на любое число в диапазоне 1-12 то всё заработает, но если это делает цикл, то ничего не работает, я пытался конвертировать данные в строку и в число но ничего, также я пробовал не пользоваться Jquery но писало ошибку, прошу помочь

---

```
var div = document.createElement('div'); // Создание основного блока
div.id = 'block';

function getRandomInt(max) { // Функция которая создает случайное число
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    let chance = getRandomInt(101);
    var pages = document.createElement('div'); //Создание блоков
    pages.id = 'page'+i;
    pages.innerHTML += i;

    if (chance > 0 && chance < 53) {
        console.log('grey', '#page'+i)
        $('#page'+i).css('background','grey'); // если написать $('#page1')... то всё прекрасно работает, но если 1 в i то ничего не работает
         
    }else if (chance > 53 && chance < 100){
        console.log('blue', '#page'+i)
        $('#page'+i).css('background','blue');
  
    }

    document.body.appendChild(div).appendChild(pages);  // Добавление всех блоков в основной блок

}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link href="GenerationStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</html>




#block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

#block div {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
```

---

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Попробуйте сделать вместо `'#page'+i` так ` `#page${i}` `

Comment: `Jquery.css` я правильно прочел?(.. пс.. **SwaD** по сути разницы нет в данном случае)
.. солидарен с первым комментарием.. вопрос ппц не очень

Comment: А как JQuery может найти $('#page'+i), если pages ещё не добавлено в документ?